# Getting the Selected Picklist Value Using Apex Trigger

Tags: trigger, picklist

I have two custom objects : `Obj1__c` and `Obj2__c`.

```
Obj1__c fields: Name, Customer__c, Date__c, Picklist__c(Red,Blue)
Obj2__c fields: Name, Customer__c, Type__c(Type1, Type2)
```

I created an apex trigger wherein a new `Obj1__c` record must be created every time a new `Obj2__c` is inserted. I have no problem with this.

Here's what I need to achieve:

`Picklist__c` field from `Obj1__c` must be inserted with this value: 'Red' if `Type__c` from `Obj2__c` is equal to 'Type1', while 'Blue' if `Type__c` from `Obj2__c` is equal to 'Type2'.

I am not so sure on how to get the selected picklist value so that I can assign it on a string variable.

Meanwhile, here's what I've done so far:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Obj2__c (after insert) {

    String selectedPV;
    List<Obj1__c> o1List = new List<Obj1__c>();

    for(Obj2__c o2 : Trigger.New) {

        if(o2.Id != null) { 

            Obj1__c o1 = new Obj1__c();
            o1.Customer__c = o2.Customer__c;
            o1.Date__c = Datetime.now();
            o1List.add(o1);
        }
    }

    insert o1List;
}
```

**Updated Trigger:**

```
trigger MyTrigger on Obj2__c (after insert) {

    List<Obj1__c> o1List = new List<Obj1__c>();

    for(Obj2__c o2 : Trigger.New) {

        Obj1__c o1 = new Obj1__c();
        String selectedPV = o2.Type__c;

        if(selectedPV == 'Type1') {
            o2.Picklist__c = 'Red';
        }

        else {
            o2.Picklist__c = 'Blue';
        } 

        if(o2.Id != null) { 


            o1.Customer__c = o2.Customer__c;
            o1.Date__c = Datetime.now();
            o1.Picklist__c = selectedPV;
            o1List.add(o1);
        }
    }

    insert o1List;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this logic:

```
if((o2.Type__c).equalsIgnoreCase('Type1'))
{
    o1.Picklist__c = 'Red';
}
else if((o2.Type__c).equalsIgnoreCase('Type2'))
{
    o1.Picklist__c = 'Blue';
}
```

> **Update** 
>   Remove `o1.Picklist__c = selectedPV;` from the assignment as you are assigning Red or Blue depending on the `if-else` logic.

Comment: Hi. Is there any way in which I can make use of my string variable? I am thinking of getting the selected Type__c value and storing it in my string variable, so that I can also insert it with other fields like this : `o1.Picklist__c = selectedPV;`

Comment: Yes, you can.    String selectedPV = o2.Type__c;

Comment: I've modified my post with the updated trigger. It saves successfully, but every time I try it on the record itself, it gives me this error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MyTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Picklist: bad value for restricted picklist field: Type1: [Picklist__c] Trigger.MyTrigger, on this line `insert o1List;`

Comment: "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST" I guess the error already tells you whats wrong with it. The Picklist__c field is marked as Restricted Picklist and hence it wont accept the values other than what is defined in the Field itself (if RT exists it would be based on them).